# How can I extract a specific variable from a webpage when I know the location of the word in python 3.x

Tags: python, find, readline, seek

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
r = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
aa1 = "text-xlarge text-semibold text-primary text-uppercase"
gr = r.find(aa1)
gr = gr+55
r.seek(gr)
print(r.readline())
```

I get error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'  after the r.seek(gr)
```

Comment: I have saved 'r' to a file and reopened it to see if that helped.  I got a new error: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: I found an answer to the problem.  The solution is below:                                             
aa2 = soup.find("div", class_="text-xlarge text-semibold text-primary text-uppercase")
print(aa2.text)
aa3 = soup.find("div", class_="text-large text-info")
print(aa3.text)
aa4 = soup.find("div", class_="text-large text-warning")
print(aa4.text)
aa5 = soup.find("div", class_="text-large text-success")
print(aa5.text)